# How to solve lack of data on contentful using graphql and gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I have the `allContentfulModelMarketingLanding` model  on contentful and it contains `components` with optional `ContentfulPartChapter` and `ContentfulPartElementsChapter`models.

Those two models are optional and can be empty but in case lack of data on one of them i get the next error:

`Cannot read property 'allContentfulModelMarketingLanding' of undefined`.

On test query page my query looks like:

```
{
  allContentfulModelMarketingLanding {
    nodes {
      components {
        ... on ContentfulPartPhotoGallery{
          id
          internal {
            type
          }
        }
        ... on ContentfulPartElementsChapter {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tired to configure `gatsby-node.js` file to avoid this error by adding:

```
type ContentfulModelMarketingLanding implements Node{
    components: ContentfulPartPhotoGallery
    components: ContentfulPartElementsChapter 
  }
```

but it didn't work like with regular fields, please tell me what can i do in case i have models inside model ?